# Sort hierarchical table CTE query

Tags: t-sql, hierarchy

How I can sort a hierarchical table with CTE query ?

sample table :

```
|ID|Name  |ParentID|
| 0|      |-1      |
| 1|1     |0       |
| 2|2     |0       |
| 3|1-1   |1       |
| 4|1-2   |1       |
| 5|2-1   |2       |
| 6|2-2   |2       |
| 7|2-1-1 |5       |
```

and my favorite result is :

```
|ID|Name  |ParentID|Level
| 0|      |-1      |0
| 1|1     |0       |1
| 3|1-1   |1       |2
| 4|1-2   |1       |2
| 2|2     |0       |1
| 5|2-1   |2       |2
| 7|2-1-1 |5       |3
| 6|2-2   |2       |2
```

another Sample :

an other sample :

```
|ID|Name      |ParentID|
| 0|          |-1      |
| 1|Book      |0       |
| 2|App       |0       |
| 3|C#        |1       |
| 4|VB.NET    |1       |
| 5|Office    |2       |
| 6|PhotoShop |2       |
| 7|Word      |5       |
```

and my favorite result is :

```
|ID|Name      |ParentID|Level
| 0|          |-1      |0
| 1|Book      |0       |1
| 3|C#        |1       |2
| 4|VB.NET    |1       |2
| 2|App       |0       |1
| 5|Office    |2       |2
| 7|Word      |5       |3
| 6|PhotoShop |2       |2
```

Comment: What is the rule for this? This is ordered by name but not by the level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) datatype is able to represent hierarchical data, and already has the desired sorting order. If you can't *replace* your `ParentID` column, then you can convert to it on the fly:

(Most of this script is data setup, the actual answer is quite small)

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,Name varchar(10) not null,ParentID int not null)
insert into @t(ID,Name,ParentID)
select 0,''          ,-1 union all
select 1,'Book'      ,0  union all
select 2,'App'       ,0  union all
select 3,'C#'        ,1  union all
select 4,'VB.NET'    ,1  union all
select 5,'Office'    ,2  union all
select 6,'PhotoShop' ,2  union all
select 7,'Word'      ,5

;With Sensible as (
    select ID,Name,NULLIF(ParentID,-1) as ParentID
    from @t
), Paths as (
    select ID,CONVERT(hierarchyid,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(10),ID) + '/') as Pth
    from Sensible where ParentID is null
    union all
    select s.ID,CONVERT(hierarchyid,p.Pth.ToString() + CONVERT(varchar(10),s.ID) + '/')
    from Sensible s inner join Paths p on s.ParentID = p.ID
)
select
    *
from
    Sensible s
        inner join
    Paths p
        on
            s.ID = p.ID
order by p.Pth
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY Name` should work as desired:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
    SELECT parent.*, 0 AS Level
    FROM @table parent
    WHERE parent.ID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT parent.*, Level+1
    FROM @table parent
    INNER JOIN CTE prev ON parent.ParentID = prev.ID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Name
```

Here's your sample data(add it next time yourself):

```
declare @table table(ID int,Name varchar(10),ParentID int);
insert into @table values(0,'',-1);
insert into @table values(1,'1',0);
insert into @table values(2,'2',0);
insert into @table values(3,'1-1',1);
insert into @table values(4,'1-2',1);
insert into @table values(5,'2-1',2);
insert into @table values(6,'2-2',2);
insert into @table values(7,'2-1-1',5);
```

Result:

```
ID  Name    ParentID    Level
0             -1          0
1    1         0          1
3    1-1       1          2
4    1-2       1          2
2    2         0          1
5    2-1       2          2
7    2-1-1     5          3
6    2-2       2          2
```

Comment: this table is sample
and "Name" field may be every character

Comment: @Mehdi: Then provide a better sample. Actually it's not clear what your rules are. How do you want to order?